# What is the difference between the first code and the second code and why should I add getString?

Tags: android, kotlin

first code with  resources.getString

```
  btn_w.setOnClickListener {  Toast.makeText(this ,resources.getString(R.string.app_name) ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
```

second code without  resources.getString

```
 btn_w.setOnClickListener {  Toast.makeText(this ,R.string.app_name ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
```

Comment: The first one is just a shortcut for the second one. It is function overloading which is very common in API designs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of code looks up the appropriate string based on your resource ID (e.g. `R.string.app_name`'s string resource may be "My App").

The second line of code just has your string's "resource ID". This ID is a number that can be used to look up the actual string (e.g. `R.string.app_name`'s resource ID may be 1234567890).

The [documentation on app resources, specifically resource IDs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ResourcesFromCode), maybe be useful.

Answer (score 2):

There are two versions of `makeText()` methods, one accepts string resource ID and another accepts String itself. You don't have to add `getString()`. If you have string resource ID, you can call the corresponding method.

```
Toast.makeText(this, R.string.some_string_resource, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

There's no difference in functionality. In fact, the method accepting `int` calls the method accepting `String` inside.

```
public static Toast makeText(Context context, @StringRes int resId, @Duration int duration) throws Resources.NotFoundException {
    return makeText(context, context.getResources().getText(resId), duration);
}

public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, @Duration int duration) {
    ...
}
```

[Toast source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/Toast.java#311).

In case you don't know what is string resource then use the link from @JakeSteam answer :)